# ServiceStack LoadReferences when using SQL Query

Tags: c#, sql-server, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

Is it possible to Load References when instead of using the code below:

```
SqlExpression<Customer> q = db.From<Customer>();
q.Join<Customer,CustomerAddress>((cust,address) => cust.Id == address.CustomerId);

List<Customer> dbCustomers = db.LoadSelect(q);
```

Using this:

```
public class KpiTotal : IKpiTotal
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public double Total { get; set; }
}

var result = dbCon.SelectFmt<KpiTotal>(@"select convert(date, t.TransactionDate) [Date], tm.TeamId,a.AccountNumber, count(distinct(t.RequisitionNumber)) Total
                                    from task.tblTransactions t
                                    inner join task.tblRequisitions r on r.RequisitionNumber = t.RequisitionNumber
                                    inner join task.tblAccounts a on a.AccountNumber = r.AccountNumber
                                    inner join Team tm on tm.DivisionId = a.DivisionId
                                    where t.TransactionTypeNumber = 201 and a.IsActive = 1 
                                    and t.TransactionDate between {0} and {1}
                                    group by convert(date, t.TransactionDate), tm.TeamName, a.AccountName
                                    order by 1,2 desc", dateRange.Start, dateRange.End);
```

Because my result object (KpiTotal) has references to two child tables, and I would like to automatic load the references, instead of getting it with a foreach block.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to load in `Team` and `Account` from the above query.  The `LoadSelect` method sniffs the POCO model and generates a query that pulls back all related DB records based on the foreign key relationships to the core object you're querying.  It generates a query similar to this for each referenced / joined POCO (very pseudo-coded):

```
SELECT * FROM Team /* Related POCO */
WHERE Team.Id IN (SELECT TeamId FROM [original query with WHERE clase])
```

Basically, it does a single query to bring back all `Teams`s or `Accounts`.

With [ServiceStack.OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) v4.0.40, there is now a new [Merge extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets) that will stitch together object references based in a more manual process.

In your case, you can query your `KpiTotal` results, then run just two separate queries to fetch back `Team` and `Account` lists, then merge them in.  Basically:

```
var result = dbCon.SelectFmt<KpiTotal>(/* gnarly SQL */);
var teams = dbCon.Select(/* get all relevant teams */);
var accounts = dbCon.Select(/* get all relevant accounts */);

result.Merge(teams);
result.Merge(accounts);

Debug.WriteLine(result.Dump());    // Output to console / debug window, whatever
```